# What speed variation would there be in a realistic LEO orbit at a nominal height of 200 km?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, orbital

So in a previous question, [How much variation in orbit altitude is caused by gravitational variation, in LEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43666/how-much-variation-in-orbit-altitude-is-caused-by-gravitational-variation-in-le) we established that an LEO orbit of ~200 km would actually change altitude by up to +/-20 km.

My question is, what speed variation would there be, if any, over the course of such an orbit?  Precision better than order of magnitude not required but appreciated.

Comment: You think of a circular orbit or an elliptical one? But at a height of 200 km the orbit would decay within a few weeks.

Comment: Circular orbit.  Orbital decay isn't an issue; I'm trying to understand the impact on speed and it's interaction with height.  At a higher orbit, decay would take longer, I accept,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same simulation of the linked question I obtain the following result:

[image]

The Earth's gravity field is modeled with the SGG-UGM-1 gravity model truncated to the degree and order 15 (for this kind of simulation, J2 + J3 would suffice). No atmosphere.

Comment: Perfect, and this leads to a third, rather more crazy question when I'm at a PC